# Scott Amblers High-low (object identification) strategy implementation and DORM

Tags: delphi, object, identity

I refer to Scott Amblers's [Choosing a Primary Key: Natural or Surrogate?](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/keys.html) page.

Excerpt:

> **High-low strategy**.  The basic idea is that your key value, often
>   called a persistent object identifier (POID) or simply an object
>   identified (OID), is in two logical parts: *A unique HIGH value* that
>   you obtain from a defined source and an *N-digit LOW value* that your
>   application assigns itself.  Each time that a HIGH value is obtained
>   the LOW value will be set to zero.

I am interested in [DORM](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-orm/) (The Delphi ORM by Daniele Teti) and would like to know if somebody has already implemented the high/low strategy for it.

Any input are welcome.

**Edit 1:**

To narrow the scope of the question:

- I want to use **Firebird** as the RDMS backend
- I likely have to implement **IdormKeysGenerator** similarly to *dorm.adapter.Firebird.TFirebirdTableSequence*.

**Edit 2:**

- *HIGH value* is persisted on the Server
- *LOW value* allocation is the client responsability.

I think an usual allocator will do for the LOW value (Implemented as a class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently DORM support only surrogate keys (integer or string). In the internal roadmap is scheduled the natural (multi field keys) key support. Some internal structures are ready to support the multiple fields keys, but still is not implemented. The high-low strategy is not planned, but should not be so difficult to do.

P.S. As is every Open Source project, feel free to contribute :-)